# Why is NAnt executing my sql scripts in the wrong order?

Tags: t-sql, nant

Here is my Script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="createAndPopulateDB" default="deploy">
    <property name="sql.connstring" value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=G-PC\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <property name="createDB" value="BuildTestDatabase.sql" />
    <property name="populateDB" value="CreateTables.sql"/>
<target name="deploy">
    <echo message="* Connecting to ${sql.connstring}"/>
    <foreach item="File" property="sql.script">
        <in>
            <items>
                <include name="${createDB}" /> 
                <include name="${populateDB}" />
            </items>
        </in>
        <do>
            <echo message="* Executing ${path::get-file-name(sql.script)}"/>
            <sql connstring="${sql.connstring}" delimiter="go" delimstyle="Line" batch="false" source="${sql.script}"/>
        </do>
    </foreach>
</target>
</project>
```

The NAnt script is supposed to call two tsql programs.  The first tsql is designed to drop a database if it is present, and if it isn't, create it.  The second checks to see if a table is present, and if so, delete it.  Similarly if it isn't, it populates the created database with a simple table.

My question is why does it run the populateDB script first?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the best way to determine the order in which the tsql programs are run is through a depends attribute attached to separate targets.  This will run them in a predetermined order and is extremely easy to follow logically if the NAnt script is a part of a repository.